# Convert a key of JCEKS of a provider into another store for another provider

Tags: java, keytool

I have a keystore JCEKS create with the SUN PROVIDER.

I have to use the same store on a IBM JDK that doesn't have the SUN PROVIDER. How can i convert the keystore or export the key using keytool in order to let the IBM JDK to access the key in the keystore?

Answer (score 1):

IBM's JDK cannot load the keystore created using SUN's JDK. So on an IBM machine, if you want to use a keystore, it should be created using IBM's JDK only.

For creating new keystore using IBM's JDK refer [this](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ap34025_.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IBMJCE with a JCEKS keystore created using SunJCE. It might be possible that using keytool a password was provided for both the keystore as well as a separate password for the securekey itself. When using keyman IBM Key Manager or your own classes with the IBMJCE to get the secure key from the JCEKS you may get com.sun.crypto.provider.SealedObjectForKeyProtector error. The solution is to set the password for the keystore and the securekey to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

`JCEKS` is a SUN format type introduced with `JCE`.

That does not mean that it is supported only by SUNs/Oracles' JDK.

You should be able to use it in an IBM JDK as well (using the IBM providers of course). Check out [IBM Security](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.IBMDI.doc_7.1/adminguide36.htm)

Comment: I have tried this, and although IBM JDK supports JCEKS as is documented it can not load a JCEKS key store created by equivalent Sun JDK. Getting an exception "java.io.IOException: com.sun.crypto.provider.SealedObjectForKeyProtector at com.ibm.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source) at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:414)" - Interestingly, a KeyStore created by the IBM JDK keytool seems to work fine when loaded in the Sun/Oracle JDK.

Comment: @ammianus:I don't find it hard to believe this without even trying it.I have experienced many differences between IBM and SUN and it does not surprise me.Thanks for sharing

Comment: Thanks, but actually I have a correction on my comment. I had a mistake in my test that pulled the wrong key store file on the Sun side. IBM keytool generated JCEKS keystore also fails when loading on Sun JRE: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: com.ibm.crypto.provider.DESedeKey
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_z.a(DashoA13*..)

Comment: Did anybody find solution for this ? I want to create key-store which is compatible with both oracle as well as IBM JDK. I have tried PKCS12  format but in PKCS12 DES algorithm is not supported. Are there any other option which I should try ?