# JCEKS keystore no longer loading: com.sun.crypto.provider.SealedObjectForKeyProtector

Tags: java, google-app-engine, aes, keystore

I have a JCEKS keystore to hold my AES keys.
This has been working in the dev environment and in the GAE runtime for a while.

Last night I deployed an update (nothing to do with the crypto cases) and now loading the keystore throws an IOException: *com.sun.crypto.provider.SealedObjectForKeyProtector* and subsequently none of my crypto works (as you'd expect given I can't get to the keys).

I've Googled the exception - one lead looked promising:
[Convert a key of JCEKS of a provider into another store for another provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175085/convert-a-key-of-jceks-of-a-provider-into-another-store-for-another-provider)
... which suggests that a keytore created with one provider cannot be read with another provider, but that doesn't seem to be the case here as it was working yesterday!  Also https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-Password_Vaults_for_Sensitive_Strings.html suggests incompatible providers.

I rolled back my app to the previous (working) version, but I get the same error.

Has GAE changed its default provider?  Should I explicitly declare the required provider in my code?

Thanks
Steve

**Update 20/05/2015 - root cause identified**

The problem was the IOException thrown by ks.load() below:

```
final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE_JCEKS);
try {
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("squirrol.keystore");
    ks.load(is, getKeystorePassword().toCharArray()); // IOException thrown here
    ...
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
    throw new KeyStoreException("Failed to load KeyStore: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

The stack trace output leads off with:

```
at com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(JceKeyStore.java:844)
```

Googling the class name has found the source (possibly not *the actual* source, but the line number in the stack trace aligns). Line 844 suggests this IOException is thrown as the result of a ClassNotFoundException with the message being the name of the class that wasn't found - in this case com.sun.crypto.provider.SealedObjectForKeyProtector:

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/crypto/provider/JceKeyStore.java.html

So, root cause is that the Google App Engine runtime v1.9.21 cannot load the keystore because it cannot load the class com.sun.crypto.provider.SealedObjectForKeyProtector which Google admit is a whitelisting issue.

**Temporary resolution**
As the result of a support ticket, Google have reverted my runtime back to 1.9.20 which doesn't have this problem.  I'm awaiting a fix that allows me to get back onto automated engine updates.

**Update 04/06/15 - Resolved**
Google will have a fix in the v1.9.22 runtime.

**Update 11/06/15 - Not Resolved after all**
The problem persists in the v1.9.22 runtime :(

**Update 30/06/15 - Really resolved & proven**
Google fixed it in the v1.9.23 runtime.  Answer updated to reflect.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This probably requires more information from your side; we currently cannot determine how you load the keys. Code would be most welcome. You probably misspelled "JCEKS" keystore as "JCSKS" in the first sentence?

Comment: I have also been receiving this message and I haven't made any updates to my app. I first received the message on 16th May:   `InputStream stream = AesDecryptor.class.getResourceAsStream(KEYSTORE);
  try {
   KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
   keystore.load(stream, AesDecryptor.PASSWORD.toCharArray());
   return keystore;
  } finally {
   stream.close();
  }
`. The exception occurs on the `keystore.load` line.

Comment: It also seems to work ok when run locally in the Google Eclipse plugin.

Comment: I got word that Google know about this and they are working on it. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11970

Comment: Apologies for the delay.

I've discovered the issue is with the whitelisting of the Sun JCE classes needed to load the JCEKS keystore on the 1.19.21 runtime.

I've traced the IOException to:
com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(JceKeyStore.java:844) according to:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/crypto/provider/JceKeyStore.java.html
would be due to a ClassNotFoundException when loading the Keystore.

I raised a support ticket with Google - they've switched my runtime back to 1.19.20 and it works again.  Google are looking at a proper fix.  I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Any updates? I've had to open a support ticket too.

Comment: Hi Rori, I've just posted an update that Google will have a resolution in the 1.19.22 runtime.  As previously mentioned my app has been regressed back to the 1.19.20 runtime.  When 1.19.22 is available I'll be switched back to regular updates.

Comment: Thanks for the update @SteveCornish , they aren't updating the ticket I opened.

Comment: @Dan it's odd - they're not even listing it as a known issue. I raised mine as a P1 because it killed my app.

Answer (score 1):

This is confirmed fixed in the GAE runtime 1.9.23 (not 1.9.22 - it missed the cut).

The problem was with the runtime whitelisting, which omitted one or more classes needed to load the JCEKS keystore.

This problem only affects the GAE runtimes 1.9.21 & 1.9.22. Note this is the server engine version, not the SDK version. You can check the server version in the console.

Comment: Bad news - this is not fixed in 1.9.22 after all.  I'm chasing the fix - will keep you posted

Comment: I'm actually seeing some curious things atm - some requests are succeeding and some are failing. These are all with the 1.9.22 runtime. The success appears consistent for each distinct instance, i.e. for any one instance all requests either succeed or fail...

Comment: @DanGravell perhaps your instances were using different runtimes?  I can definitely say that the 1.9.23 runtime is finally fixed.